# Customising layout change animation on UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a UICollectionView that has two layout's (list style like uitableview and gallery style which is a full screen horizontal item scroller).

The cell contains a single image and two labels (title & description). In list layout the image is on the left and labels on the right. In gallery layout the image is full width & 50% height with labels beneath. Like this:

[image]

The default animation when switching between these two layouts is too simply resize and move the cells to their new positions in the layout. However I want to make a much more specific animation.

Specifically these are the rough steps I want the animation to take when going from list to gallery view:

1. Fade out all but the first visible cell (aka cell 1)
2. Fade out the labels in cell 1
3. Grow the width of the image in cell 1 to 100%
4. Grow height of cell 1 to full screen (with the image height following the cell growing - to 40% height)
5. Fade back in the labels for cell 1
6. Show the other cells (although they should be off screen - so this may not be neccessary)

The steps would pretty much reverse for gallery -> list layout change.

The UICollectionViewFlowLayout is perfect for the layouts that i want to achieve, I just want to have a much finer control over the animation so that I can produce this "stepped animation" (or would this be like keyframe animation?)

It probably doesn't matter much - but i'm using auto layout constraints (via SnapKit) wherever possible and i'd like to maintain that where i can.

Of course I don't expect someone to program all this for me, however Google isn't helping me work out where to start.

Could someone please point me in the right direction of which methods I need to be implementing/overriding on which classes, and maybe a hint of pseudo-code?

Comment: I think you can create one custom view (look like your first cell) for animation and when animation started you can hide your collectionView and show this custom view. You can use different constraints and change constraints priorities `customViewHeightConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority.defaultLow`. After animation ends you can show your collectionView with new layout.